# How do I access data correctly in a JSON.parse statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqplot

I'm trying to work with a JSON array that's been returned via an AJAX call. I'd like to put this data in JQPlot to graph it. When I use hard coded dummy data my graph draws fine. The dummy data looks like this:

```
    var s1 = [200, 600, 700, 1000];
    var s2 = [460, -210, 690, 820];
    var s3 = [-260, -440, 320, 200];
    var ticks = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'August'];
```

My attempt to use my own data comes from an ajax call into 'garray' and looks like this:

```
    var obj = JSON.stringify(garray);
    alert(obj);
    /*this displays the following:
    {"date":[["2015-05-29","2015-05-12","2015-04-30","2015-03-30","2015-02-27","2015-02-26"]],"close":[[0,3,1,1,0,0]],"high":[[1,3,2,1,0,1]],"low":[[0,-1,0,-1,-1,-1]]} */

obj = JSON.parse(obj);
s1 = obj["date"];
alert(s1);
//the alert above displays: 2015-05-29,2015-05-12,2015-04-30,2015-03-30,2015-02-27,2015-02-26
```

The problem is that this separation is being interpreted as one variable in JQPlot, as opposed to separate dates. The exact same is happening with the other strings, so I suspect I'm not processing them correctly? Do I need to use a different approach?

Comment: `s1 = obj["date"][0];
alert(s1);`

Comment: shouldn't be needing to stringify the data...where and why is that being used?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the fields you have (`date`, `close`, etc.) is actually an array of arrays (notice the double `[[` and `]]` at the beginning in ending -- an array just needs one of those). My guess is that the API you're using can return multiple sets of data, and you're just asking for one.

So, you should use `obj["date"][0]` (and similarly for the others)

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = obj["date"]; // is an array of dates
for( var i = 0; i < s1.length; i++ ){
  console.log(s1[i]) // logs each date in the array
}
```

Comment: suggest replacing `obj` with `garray` since stringify then parse in OP code is a waste ... `obj` appears to be debugging code